# Child div with border within parent div with border, gap on right edge

Tags: html, css, wordpress

So I have a child div with a border within parent div with a border. The child div has 3 tabs all with a width of 33.3334%. but there is tiny gap at the end of the tabs between the child border and the parent border. See the picture:
[image]

I need to get rid of this gap, so that the border of the parent is the only one visible. Making the tab widths any bigger pushes the 3rd one onto the next line.

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

```css
    li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active {
      background-color: #a0a3a2;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top {
      width: 33.3334%;
      border-right: 2px solid #a0a3a2;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #a0a3a2;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    #ui-id-3.ui-tabs-anchor {
      width: 33.3334%;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px!important;
    }
    .woocommerce-tabs {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: 2px solid #adb0b2;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wpb_tabs wpb_content_element" data-interval="0">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper wpb_tour_tabs_wrapper ui-tabs vc_clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="wpb_tabs_nav ui-tabs-nav vc_clearfix ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-6f4746f8-2705-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#tab-6f4746f8-2705-5" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">PRODUCT DETAILS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-42783517-3ace-8" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#tab-42783517-3ace-8" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">DELIVERY DETAILS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-1429777272805-2-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#tab-1429777272805-2-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">REVIEWS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle or show the site on temporary server?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure how to do that :/

Comment: @PeterKirkwood Currently you provided code look like: http://jsfiddle.net/ssdqzqa3/

Comment: Thanks for that. I've been working on it, but I think because it's wordpress, I can't locate all the CSS rules that format it like that. I'll keep trying!

Comment: @ketan We don't need jsfiddle on Stack Overflow. I've edited the question using the code snippet feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you get rid of the gap, you'll still have a double border so you also need to get rid of one of the borders. You can hide the border on the last `li` with this:

```
li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
```

But you may still have a gap in the bottom border.

Without seeing the rest of your styling, it's hard to say for sure, but often these unwanted gaps are caused by whitespace in the HTML. This seems counter-intuitive because usually whitespace doesn't matter, but between images and inline block elements it often introduces unwanted gaps.

Unfortunately (to my knowledge) there isn't an elegant solution to this issue. There are hacky solutions using CSS (e.g. set the font-size to zero for the parent element and set an explicit font size for your `li` elements), but the easiest is to just remove the whitespace between the `</li>` and the `</ul>`. See https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/ for more suggestions.

Run the snippet below for a demonstration - I've replaced the whitespace (including newline) with a comment, which is fine as long as there's no whitespace around the comment.

```css
/* hide the border on the last li */
li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

/* original CSS from the question - no changes here */
li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active {
      background-color: #a0a3a2;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top {
      width: 33.3334%;
      border-right: 2px solid #a0a3a2;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #a0a3a2;
      border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    }
    #ui-id-3.ui-tabs-anchor {
      width: 33.3334%;
      border-top-right-radius: 0px!important;
    }
    .woocommerce-tabs {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      border: 2px solid #adb0b2;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      padding: 5px;
    }

/* not part of answer - just here to make the snippet more closely
   match the image in the question */
ul {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wpb_tabs wpb_content_element" data-interval="0">
  <div class="wpb_wrapper wpb_tour_tabs_wrapper ui-tabs vc_clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="wpb_tabs_nav ui-tabs-nav vc_clearfix ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
      <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tab-6f4746f8-2705-5" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <a href="#tab-6f4746f8-2705-5" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">PR</a>
      </li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-42783517-3ace-8" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#tab-42783517-3ace-8" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">DE</a>
      </li><li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tab-1429777272805-2-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">
        <a href="#tab-1429777272805-2-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">RE</a>
      </li><!-- you can have a comment here, just no whitespace--></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.your first bit of CSS has helped, I'll try the other bits as soon as I can (Have to go out now I'm afraid)

Comment: Sure thing. Note that if your outer border is on one of the `div` elements rather than the `ul`, you might need to remove more whitespace to completely eliminate the gap. It's only whitespace between a `>` and an immediately-following `<` that matters - if there's already text in there, the whitespace won't matter.

Comment: I can't edit the white space as it's within Visual Compser. I think I'm going to make the background of the <ul> the same color, then use :before and :after to colour the rounded corners. Messy, but I need to do the before and after rounded corners anyway!

Comment: If you can't edit the whitespace, the `font-size` trick might work for you. And there are others. Have a look at https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Taking out the right border of tab three and making the <ul> background grey has really helped - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using **CSS3** `box-sizing` property will solve your problem.

### CSS

```
div.container {
    border: 2px solid #888;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.tab {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul.tab > li {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-right: 2px solid #888;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #888;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    color: #888;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3334%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul.tab > li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
ul.tab > li.active {
    background-color: #888;
    color: #fff;
}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<ul class="tab">
<li class="active">PRODUCT DETAILS</li>
<li>DELIVERY DETAILS</li>
<li>REVIEWS</li>
</ul>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/yd6ao3d4/